# Problem with breakable tcolorbox and Underfull \vbox

Tags: tcolorbox

How to fix Underfull \vbox and why the textcolor is white after breakable tcolorbox? Those appeared as problems after the update of some packages, the tcolorbox one of them. Until these updates, using the same code and everything has been working correctly.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}

\usepackage[top=3.5cm,
            headheight=1.5cm,
            headsep=1cm,
            bottom=3cm,
            footskip=1.5cm,
            left=2cm,
            right=2cm,
            heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\frenchspacing
\onehalfspacing
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newtcolorbox{test}{
    empty, breakable, top=0mm, bottom=0mm, left=9mm,
    fonttitle=\large\bfseries, coltitle=black, title=mybox,
    subtitle style=empty,
    borderline west={0.5mm}{5mm}{black!50},
}

\newenvironment{mybox}{
    \begin{test}
}{\end{test} \par\bigskip}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}
    \blindtext[4]
\end{mybox}

{\bfseries\color{red} problem 1: Underfull vbox (badness 10000) has occured while output is active}

\begin{mybox}
    \blindtext[2]
\end{mybox}

{\bfseries\color{blue} after box text is fine}

\begin{mybox}
    \blindtext
\end{mybox}

{\bfseries\color{blue} after box text is fine}

\begin{mybox}
    \blindtext
\end{mybox}

{\bfseries\color{orange} problem 2: after breakable box textcolor is white and doesn't show}

\begin{mybox}
    \blindtext
\end{mybox}

{\bfseries\color{blue} after box text is fine}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The second problem, white textcolor after breakable tcolorbox, has been resolved in `tcolorbox` v4.41. See the related issue: https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/issues/120.

Comment: The problem occurred because of this version 4.41

Comment: Ok, now I see the problem. I've reported it to `tcolorbox`'s maintainer, see [here](https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/issues/120#issuecomment-705867797).

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you have any idea to fix underfull \vbox? I added the option "heightrounded" in geometry package but nothing.

Comment: The underfull `\vbox` warning is reproducible even with texlive 2019 on Overleaf.com, and I think it is caused by the fact TeX thinks the first page break is not good enough. Inserting manual page break like `\newpage` or changing vertical alignment by `\raggedbottom` would both eliminate the warning.

Comment: The color problem is (hopefully) resolved with version 4.42 (2020-10-09).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been resolved in comments.